# prevent modal from keeping data in cache following select choice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

In my twig view, I recover from a controller query, user infortmations in a table like this:

```
<table id="userDataTables" class="display table-responsive" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="font-size: 95%;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>phone</th>
      <th>Registered at</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for user in arrayuser %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ user.username|capitalize }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.id|capitalize }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.emailCanonical }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.phone }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.createdAt|date("Y/m/d", "Europe/Paris") }}</td>
        <td>
          <select class="redirectSelect form-control">
            <option value="" disabled selected style="font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; text-transform: lowercase; color: grey;">choisir une action</option>
            <option value="{{ path('consumer_profile_edit', {'slug': user.slug }) }}">Edit Profile</option>
            <option value="{{ path('index_admin_consumer_comment_pannel', {'slug': user.slug }) }}">Show comment(s)</option>
            <option class="deleteInscription" value="#" data-href="{{ path('delete_user_process', {'id': user.id}) }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#consumerDeleteModal" style="font-weight: bold; color: #CF000F;">Delete user</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see I have a select tag like this foreach user lines in my table:

```
<select class="redirectSelect form-control">
    <option value="" disabled selected style="font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; text-transform: lowercase; color: grey;">choisir une action</option>
    <option value="{{ path('consumer_profile_edit', {'slug': user.slug }) }}">Edit Profile</option>
    <option value="{{ path('index_admin_consumer_comment_pannel', {'slug': user.slug }) }}">Show comment(s)</option>
    <option class="deleteInscription" value="#" data-href="{{ path('delete_user_process', {'id': user.id}) }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#consumerDeleteModal" style="font-weight: bold; color: #CF000F;">Delete user</option>
</select>
```

I show a modal only if an admin selected the choice "Delete user".

But, in fact the modal keeps the toggled data, so even if I choose a different user I want to delete, it's not the right which is deleted because of the modal cache I think. So I would like to find a solution to clear this cache, or to create a process as the modal target the right user id and delete the right one.

### EDIT

> The modal keeps always the first entry of user array I return in my
>   view. For example, I return an array with 20 users, with their
>   informations like ids, names, phones, emails ... etc **ORDER BY id ASC**.
>
> If I choose **user** with id **5** and I want to delete him, all my process
>   concerning the query to delete a particular user following his **id** worked well in my php script. By
>   adding a modal to prevent that this action is permanent, it **always**
>   **deletes** the **first** **entry** (so the first user with id 1 is deleted), not the user with id 5.

This is the html and the script for the modal ?

```
<div class="modal fade" id="consumerDeleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Delete user:</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="alert alert-warning">
          <p> Warning <b> this action is permanent ! </p>
        </div>
        <div id="deleteConsumerForm">
          <p> <b>Delete user permanently ?</b> </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <a alt="effacer consommateur">
          <button id="confirmDeletion" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Confirm</button>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async defer>
  // manage modal on google chrome
  $('.redirectSelect').on('change', function () {
    var url = $(this).val();
    if (url === "#") { // require a URL
      console.log(url);
      $('#consumerDeleteModal').modal()
    } else if (url !== "#") {
      console.log(url);
      window.location = url;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });

  // deleted function
  $('#confirmDeletion').bind('click', function() {
    var deleteTarget = $('.deleteInscription').attr('data-href');
    if (deleteTarget == null){
      console.log("failed !!!");
    } else {
      console.log("prepare to delete the user !!!");
      $(this).attr('href', deleteTarget);
      window.location.href = deleteTarget;
    }
  });
</script>
```

How can I proceed ?

Comment: What data is being kept in the modal, and can you show us the html that allows you to choose the user to which the action is applied?

Comment: @BenjaminRay Ray see my edit in my intial post, I hope it is more understandable

Comment: How do you specify which user to delete?  Does the array of users get converted to HTML radio buttons, checkboxes, a list, etc.?  So far all I see is the option to select the action.

Comment: @BenjaminRay I edit again my post. In my fact I recover user information in a table from a controller query I return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select the Delete option, your code does not tell the Modal which user is being deleted.  To fix this, move the declaration of `deleteTarget` to the top, and populate it when the user selects the Delete option as follows: `deleteTarget = $(this).children('.deleteInscription').attr('data-href');`

Demo:  https://jsfiddle.net/BenjaminRay/t03jwgcd/

Revised JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async defer>
 // manage modal on google chrome
  var deleteTarget = '';
  $('.redirectSelect').on('change', function () {
    var url = $(this).val();
    if (url === "#") { // require a URL
      console.log(url);
      $('#consumerDeleteModal').modal();
      deleteTarget = $(this).children('.deleteInscription').attr('data-href');
    } else if (url !== "#") {
      console.log(url);
      window.location = url;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });

  // deleted function
  $('#confirmDeletion').bind('click', function() {
    if (deleteTarget == null){
      console.log("failed !!!");
    } else {
      console.log("prepare to delete the user !!!");
      $(this).attr('href', deleteTarget);
      window.location.href = deleteTarget;
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help, it seems like I have to lean more about javascript language. You save my day.